# How to delimit comma separator in csv

Tags: csv, papaparse

I have a file that originally looked like this:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zAMjdrUf9V4, How to fix your computer harddrive, in under 5 min., 04/12/2020
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zz9pMKy9Mbs,How to Repair a DEAD Computer, 04/12/2020
```

The intent is to treat this as a file where there are two rows, with three columns in each row. To that end, I'm wrapping the middle part in quotations:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zAMjdrUf9V4, "How to fix your computer harddrive, in under 5 min.", 04/12/2020
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zz9pMKy9Mbs,How to Repair a DEAD Computer, 04/12/2020
```

My hope is that by wrapping the middle part in quotation marks, the embedded comma would be ignored, and the first row would be interpreted as having 3 columns, rather than 4.
On the API side, I originally just did this:

```
Papa.parse(files[0], {
            complete: onFileParsed
        });
```

and then later I tried this:

```
Papa.parse(files[0], {
            delimiter: ',',
            quoteChar: '"',
            complete: onFileParsed
        });
```

but it's still intrepretting the first row as having four columns instead of three.  I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong.  If so, please advise.

Answer (score 1):

The problem, it turned out was in the first line in the CSV file:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zAMjdrUf9V4, "How to fix your computer harddrive, in under 5 min.", 04/12/2020
```

The code didn't like the space between the comma and the quotation mark.  Removing it, like this:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zAMjdrUf9V4,"How to fix your computer harddrive, in under 5 min.", 04/12/2020
```

resolves the problem.

Comment: so having space is problem, did you find any alternative?

Comment: Umm, not that I remember